# Need help changing a value in an object within an array on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I'm building a book library and need help adjusting the "read" value for an object in the myLibrary array. When I click on the parent element's read status div, if the associated object's current read value is true it should change to false and vise versa. I added a function so when I click on the "read" div, it changes the read value for the object associated with it in the myLibrary array. The issue I'm running into is that it will only change the read value for the object in the array from true to false. If I click on the div and its associated object already has a read value of false nothing changes. The object's read value just stays false. The function I need help with is within the createCard() at the bottom where I create the "read" div.
Please help! Thank you!

```
const library = document.querySelector('#library');

let myLibrary = [];


class Book {
  constructor(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
  }
}

Book.prototype.addToLibrary = function () {
  myLibrary.push(this)
}

// myLibrary.push(new Book("The Hobbit", "J. R. R. Tolken", 471, read));
// myLibrary.push(new Book("Harry Potter", "J. K. Rowling", 381, read));
// myLibrary.push(new Book("Greenlights", "Matthew McConaughey", 252, read));

// submits the form
const addToLibraryBtn = document.querySelector('.modal-add-btn');

addToLibraryBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const input = document.querySelectorAll('input')
  const title = input[0].value;
  const author = input[1].value;
  const pages = input[2].value;
  const read = document.getElementById('read').value === "Yes" ? true : false;

  const book = new Book(title, author, pages, read)
  book.addToLibrary()
  clearLibrary()
  createStoredCards()
  closeModal()
  clearForm()
})

// clears the display and re-adds cards in myLibrary array so duplicate cards are not created
const clearLibrary = () =>
  library.innerHTML = ""

// clears form inputs
const clearForm = () => {
  const form = document.querySelector('form')
  form.reset()
}

// Creates the look of the card and information that each card displays
function createCard(book) {

  const card = document.createElement('div');
  card.classList.add('card');

  // Adding the remove button and function
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('div');
  removeBtn.classList.add('remove-btn');
  removeBtn.innerText = 'Remove';
  card.appendChild(removeBtn);

  // Removes card from the array and the display
  removeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteBook(myLibrary.indexOf(book), card)
  })

  // Adding the title 
  let title = document.createElement('div');
  title.classList.add('card-title');
  title.innerHTML = `Title: <span>${book.title}</span>`;
  card.appendChild(title);

  // Adding the author
  let author = document.createElement('div');
  author.classList.add('card-author');
  author.innerHTML = `Author: <span>${book.author}</span>`;
  card.appendChild(author);

  // Adding the page count
  let pages = document.createElement('div');
  pages.classList.add('card-count');
  pages.innerHTML = `Page Count: <span>${book.pages}</span>`;
  card.appendChild(pages);

  // Adding the read status
  let read = document.createElement('div');
  read.classList.add('card-read');
  read.innerHTML = `Read Status: <span class="read-status">${book.read === true ? "Read" : "Not read"}</span>`;
  card.appendChild(read);
  read.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myLibrary[myLibrary.indexOf(book)].read = true ? false : true;

    clearLibrary()
    createStoredCards()
  })

  library.appendChild(card);
}

// creates a card for each book in the myLibrary array and displays the card in the users library
function createStoredCards() {
  myLibrary.forEach(book => {
    createCard(book);
  })
}

// function that removes book
function deleteBook(bookIndex, card) {
  myLibrary.splice(bookIndex, 1);
  card.remove();
}

// Open and close modal form

const addBookBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-modal');

addBookBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.style.display = "flex";
})

const closeModal = () => modal.style.display = 'none'

window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target == modal) {
    closeModal();
  }
})

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  closeModal();
})
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] so that we can follow along.

Comment: `myLibrary[myLibrary.indexOf(book)].read = true ? false : true;` unsure what you are expecting that ternary operation to be doing.

Comment: The ternary operator is supposed to change the "read" value in the myLibrary array for that specific object from true to false if the current value is true and from false to true if the current value is false. the ternary operator is working as intended but only the first time I click on that div.

Comment: `myLibrary[myLibrary.indexOf(book)].read = true ? false : true;` always assigns false to the `read` property. You mean: `...read = (...read)? false: true;`, OR more clearly: `...read = (true === ...read)? false: true;`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles thanks a ton for for help! It works! I am relatively new to coding and did not know that. Also since the user is entering the value for that object into a form I assumed the the ternary operator would take the current value and run based off that. Just so I understand better what is happening under the hood, is the ternary operator going into the object in the array changing the read value to false first and then running the rest of the statement?

Comment: "...and then running the rest of the statement?" I don't understand what you mean by that. What's "the rest of the statement"?

Comment: Javascript [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) assigns the expression after the `?` if the conditional is true, or assigns the expression after the `:` if the conditional is false. The boolean conditional statement appears after the `=` and before the `?`. The conditional is independent from the variable or property that appears before the `=` sign. In other words the condition does not take into account what is before the `=`. The condition `(true)` is always `true`, regardless the value of `read`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your ternary conditional operator, here:

```
read.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myLibrary[myLibrary.indexOf(book)].read = true ? false : true;

  clearLibrary()
  createStoredCards()
})
```

When you write `...read = true ? false : true`, this is what happens:

1. This is an assignment statement (`=`), so it will evaluate all that is at the rigt of the assignment operator;
2. Then you have your [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It works like this:

- It check if the expression before `?` (called condition) evaluates to `true` or `false`.
- If the condition evaluates to `true` (see [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)), the result of the ternary expression is whatever is before the `:`.
- If the condition evaluates to `false` (see [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), the result of the ternary expression is whatever is after the `:`.

3. In your case, it is `true ? false : true`. The condition here is simply the constant `true`, which always evaluates to `true`. Hence, the result of the ternary expression will always be `false`, and that will be assigned to the `.read` property on every click.

To fix your code, you have to check inside the condition expression, if `.read` is truthy. Like this:

```
wasRead = myLibrary[myLibrary.indexOf(book)].read
myLibrary[myLibrary.indexOf(book)].read = wasRead ? false : true;
```

But actually, the operation you are doing is a very common one, know as "toggle". For toggling a boolean value, you just need to negate (`!`) is current value (if you do `!true`, you get `false`, and vice versa).

```
wasRead = myLibrary[myLibrary.indexOf(book)].read
myLibrary[myLibrary.indexOf(book)].read = !wasRead
```

Moreover, I don't see the point of this big expression to get the `.read` property of `book` by getting the index on the librady. You already have a reference to the book object! Why not just this?

```
book.read = !book.read
```